# Jquery selecting values from on table while in another table

Tags: jquery

I have two tables that are dynamically created (as a set).  From a button click in a cell of the second(bottom) table, I need to traverse back up to a previous table to get a value.

This line gives me table Id in which the button is in.
1)Is this the right syntax?  I don't want to accidently get another table below it (because there could be another set of two tables below this set)

> $(this).closest('table')[0].id

Now I need a way to get to the table above it. And then in that table, I need to get the the last row.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share your HTML code (or a simplified version).  Maybe create a fiddle?  There is `.siblings()` or another `.closest()` depending on what you mean by "above".  A betyter solution might be (if you can alter the HTML) to give each table a class and then put both in a common container div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming your table is directly above `$(this).closest('table')[0]`, then you can access it with `$(this).closest('table')[0].prev()`

Comment: Thanks!  I had tried .prev() and it error, so I must have typed it wrong.  I had forgotten the [0].  Thanks for the clarification.